# Create popup browser widget

Tags: javascript, php, popup

Is it possible to create something like facebooks popup-gallery but instead of showing a picture, it shows a webpage? So it has a popup function and shows another webpage with all the site's functions. I do not mean popup-window!
So the user is technically on my site, but I am showing another webpage. 
If this work, what type of coding language should I aim for? I have average skills in html,javascript and php.
Thanks for answer!

Comment: use `iframe` with a little of `javascript` and here you go, no need of PHP unless you have a table that contains each website url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `<iframe></iframe>` tag.

```
<iframe src="http://google.com"></iframe>
```

You can style it (width, height, etc) with CSS as any other HTML element.

So you're probably looking into something like this:

```
<style>
     iframe {
        position: relative;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
     }

</style>

<div class="lightbox">
    <iframe src="http://google.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

[Further reading](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an tutotial, it shows popup
if you want to call another website, than call site using file_get_contents or cult to open in the popup windows.

```js
// Validating Empty Field
function check_empty() {
if (document.getElementById('name').value == "" || document.getElementById('email').value == "" || document.getElementById('msg').value == "") {
alert("Fill All Fields !");
} else {
document.getElementById('form').submit();
alert("Form Submitted Successfully...");
}
}
//Function To Display Popup
function div_show() {
document.getElementById('abc').style.display = "block";
}
//Function to Hide Popup
function div_hide(){
document.getElementById('abc').style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
@import "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway";
/*----------------------------------------------
CSS settings for HTML div Exact Center
------------------------------------------------*/
#abc {
width:100%;
height:100%;
opacity:.95;
top:0;
left:0;
display:none;
position:fixed;
background-color:#313131;
overflow:auto
}
img#close {
position:absolute;
right:-14px;
top:-14px;
cursor:pointer
}
div#popupContact {
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:17%;
margin-left:-202px;
font-family:'Raleway',sans-serif
}
form {
max-width:300px;
min-width:250px;
padding:10px 50px;
border:2px solid gray;
border-radius:10px;
font-family:raleway;
background-color:#fff
}
p {
margin-top:30px
}
h2 {
background-color:#FEFFED;
padding:20px 35px;
margin:-10px -50px;
text-align:center;
border-radius:10px 10px 0 0
}
hr {
margin:10px -50px;
border:0;
border-top:1px solid #ccc
}
input[type=text] {
width:82%;
padding:10px;
margin-top:30px;
border:1px solid #ccc;
padding-left:40px;
font-size:16px;
font-family:raleway
}
#name {
background-image:url(../images/name.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:5px 7px
}
#email {
background-image:url(../images/email.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:5px 7px
}
textarea {
background-image:url(../images/msg.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:5px 7px;
width:82%;
height:95px;
padding:10px;
resize:none;
margin-top:30px;
border:1px solid #ccc;
padding-left:40px;
font-size:16px;
font-family:raleway;
margin-bottom:30px
}
#submit {
text-decoration:none;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
display:block;
background-color:#FFBC00;
color:#fff;
border:1px solid #FFCB00;
padding:10px 0;
font-size:20px;
cursor:pointer;
border-radius:5px
}
span {
color:red;
font-weight:700
}
button {
width:10%;
height:45px;
border-radius:3px;
background-color:#cd853f;
color:#fff;
font-family:'Raleway',sans-serif;
font-size:18px;
cursor:pointer
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Popup contact form</title>
<link href="css/elements.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/my_js.js"></script>
</head>
<!-- Body Starts Here -->
<body id="body" style="overflow:hidden;">
<div id="abc">
<!-- Popup Div Starts Here -->
<div id="popupContact">
<!-- Contact Us Form -->
<form action="#" id="form" method="post" name="form">
<img id="close" src="images/3.png" onclick ="div_hide()">
<h2>Contact Us</h2>
<hr>
<input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text">
<input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text">
<textarea id="msg" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
<a href="javascript:%20check_empty()" id="submit">Send</a>
</form>
</div>
<!-- Popup Div Ends Here -->
</div>
<!-- Display Popup Button -->
<h1>Click Button To Popup Form Using Javascript</h1>
<button id="popup" onclick="div_show()">Popup</button>
</body>
<!-- Body Ends Here -->
</html>
```

Check out the link http://www.formget.com/how-to-create-pop-up-contact-form-using-javascript/

Comment: he wants to display a URL not a form

Comment: yes, show url using file_get_contents('https:xyz.com')

Comment: this function get the content of the URL then you should parse it.

Comment: Good looking!, bu on which line should I pass in the file_get_contents('https:xyz.com') to display a website?

Comment: In popup call using php. If you like my answer, upvote and accept answer. plaese